# "No root file system is defined" dual boot Ubuntu 19.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

I am using a [DELL Inspiron 7591](https://www.dell.com/en-in/shop/laptops-2-in-1-pcs/new-inspiron-15-7591-laptop/spd/inspiron-15-7591-laptop/icc-c586502win8) laptop and I am trying to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.04. My disk partitions are 102 GB as `C:` and 106 GB as `D:` for Windows and I have around 250 GB of unallocated space for Ubuntu 19.04.

A common error that I am facing (also see screenshot below) is:

```
No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu.
```

[image: error screenshot]

The most suggested answer to this error is to select `/` as the mount point for the partition on which I would like to install Ubuntu on.

But the problem here is that I can't find the partition that I want to install Ubuntu on in the list. In fact, the disk partitions that I can find on the list are:

- The one from the bootable USB stick.
- Some 2GB loop device.

I can't find any of the hard drive partitions of the laptop.